# How to do a head deployment for a web application that allow all access?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am deploying a Google App Script as a web app.

There are two options, I can either deploy a version of the code as a web app and allow everyone to access it via:

[image]

Or I can click on the link "latest code" and access the "head" version of the code but then no one can access it except me.

How do I just push the latest code to a public facing web app? Without creating a new version each time?

Comment: I don't think you can.  However, changing the version doesn't change the url.

Comment: It doesn’t change the URL but as I am doing testing I am creating hundreds of versions

Comment: I actually prefer to do it that way.  But you don't have to you can just run the dev code.

Comment: But I cant thats why I posted, you can just run dev code as a web app that allows public access

Comment: Well once it's done create a version and distribute the exec version to everyone else.

Comment: I need to have a way to publish my code 100 times, without creating 100 versions. And have the web app be public accessible. Please explain how

Comment: You can't. Why can't you use the dev url during testing?

Comment: The dev url is not publicly accessible. You need to authenticate with google first I think otherwise you get error page

Comment: So what? You're the one using this during testing only. Right?

Comment: Well I dont even know how to do that from postman with authentication

Comment: 1.To access dev url, You can use another web-app to get access token using `ScriptApp.getOauthToken()`. This token can be sent as a header in postman to authorize. 2. A easier way to create a new version and publish web-app would be to use [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/63)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. So can I ask you about your goal? 1. You want to access to the Web Apps with the developer mode using the URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev`? 2. You want to access to the Web Apps with the latest version using the URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`? 3. You want to access to the Web Apps by selecting the version using the URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`? 4. Others?

Comment: I want to access https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev from postman. How do I do that? It just returns an error page

Comment: Hi @erotsppa! You will need an [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) authorization token in your headers. Here are the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_1) about HTTP headers. You will have to use some kind of script to refresh your tokens, but if you are planning one-time usage or very low frequency, you can do it manually with [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Answer (score 2):

From the question

> How do I just push the latest code to a public facing web app? Without creating a new version each time?

It's not possible.